# Is there a ISAPI Filter that can rewrite the Header values before passing to aspnet

Tags: iis-6, isapi

I'm trying to fix/patch the ASPNET 1.1 framework problem with the user-adgent string being too long.

Is there a ISAPI filter that could shape the USER-AGENT header before passing in to ASPNET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISAPI_Rewrite from http://www.isapirewrite.com. You should be able to change the USER_AGENT.

Comment: Although there does seem to be a bug in there RewriteHeader directive... have raised a support question to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) to see if it will do what you're looking for?  It's fairly robust.